# Remove Help Icon in Magento Backend Page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to hide or remove help icon in magento backend page,
here I show screenshot for my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you path of the files responsible for these icons and texts you want to remove.

**app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\store\switcher.phtml**

Remove below line

```
<?php echo $this->getHintHtml() ?>
```

**app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\menu.phtml**

Remove below code.

```
<a id="page-help-link" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getPageHelpUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Get help for this page') ?></a>
<script type="text/javascript">$('page-help-link').target = 'magento_page_help'</script>
```

Rewrite these files using layout and remove unwanted things.

Comment: awesome, it works. Thank you very much , you saved my time.